# Sass styles not getting applied in react

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am trying to use sass with react but its not working. The styles are not getting applied. I have used CRA. and I have also installed `sass` as per official docs of CRA. It works fine if I change scss to css.

I am mentioning the dependencies below

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"react-redux": "^8.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "0.9.5",
"redux": "^4.1.2",
"sass": "^1.50.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with react-scripts. Somehow CRA is currently shipping react-scripts version 0.9.5. Updating the react-scripts to latest version solved the issue.

Comment: Finally could find the real problem. Thank you for sharing.